# chainlink addConsumer() => "not implemented" (mockCoordinator)

Tags: javascript, solidity, chainlink

What could be the cause of reverting with this message => "not implemented"
When you call:

response = await VRFCoordinatorV2MockContract.addConsumer(ethers.utils.formatUnits(vrfSubsId, 0), myContract.address)

All contracts are deployed correctly and subscription is created and funded.

Answer (score 0):

It's because functionality for adding and removing consumers wasn't implemented at first for the `mockCoordinator` contract.

Bumping the `@chainlink/contracts` version to 0.4.2 or above should solve this issue.